# disqus where to grab access_token

Tags: access-token, disqus

Based on this [link](http://disqus.com/api/docs/auth/)

"Authenticating as the Account Owner
Many applications simply want to perform actions on behalf of the account owner. You can do this using the standard OAuth flow, except that you won't need to request an access token. Instead, visit your account details page, and grab the Access Token. This is a special access token which does not expire, and will authenticate you as the application owner."

For the life of me, I cannot seem to find the account page which holds access_token, is there anything I need to do first before seeing it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not that obvious, but go to this page: http://disqus.com/api/applications/

Then click on your application title, which will bring you to the details page. The owner access token is at the bottom of that first page after you click.